# In Excel 2013 can chart titles be read from a cell in the worksheet?

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2013, title

In Excel 2013, can the chart title and axis titles be read from cells in the spreadsheet?  If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to read Title and Axis tiles from a cell in the excel sheet.

On the chart, click on the 'Title' > click on the "Formula Bar" > enter '=' and select the cell from where you need to read the title and press 'Enter' key. Similarly for Axis titles, click on the Axis Title > click on the "Formula Bar" > enter '=' and select the cell from where you need to read the title and press 'Enter' key. Refer the screenshot.

Calculation is the Title of the chart. Month and Values are the Axis Titles.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  Got that now.  I tried that before but I must have done something wrong.